# How can I use `bound` for non-monads?

Tags: haskell, package, logic, monads, dsl

I am trying to use the [bound package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound-2.0.1) to represent terms and propositions in a simple logical language. Here is what I have so far:

```hs
import Bound

data Term a = V a
            | Func String [Term a]
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

data Prop a = And (Prop a) (Prop a)
            | Relation String [Term a]
            | Forall (Scope () Prop a)
            deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

In particular, there are terms which are either variables, or functions applied to some terms, as well as propositions which are: conjunction of two propositions, a relation applied to some terms, and quantification over variables in another proposition.
But when I try to create a function to construct a "Forall", following the example in the package documentation, I am told that `Prop` is not a monad:

```
forall' :: Eq a => a -> Prop a -> Prop a
forall' v b = Forall (abstract1 v b)
```

This is expected, since I didn't define `Monad Prop`. But there is no sensible `pure` (or `return`) into `Prop`, so how can I support this language using the `bound` package?

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to merge `Term` and `Prop` here:

```
data Exp a
  = V a
  | Func String [Exp a]
  | And (Exp a) (Exp a)
  | Relation String [Exp a]
  | Forall (Scope () Prop a)
```

If I understand correctly, the `Applicative`/`Monad` structure that `abstract1` wants is supposed to have `pure` inject a variable and `>>=` do substitution. With this, your `Applicative` and `Monad` instances can straightforwardly follow the documentation:

```
instance Applicative Exp where
  pure = V
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Exp where
  return = V
  V a           >>= f = f a
  And x y       >>= f = And (x >>= f) (y >>= f)
  Relation r xs >>= f = Relation r (fmap (>>= f) xs)  -- (I think.)
  Forall e      >>= f = Forall (e >>>= f)             -- NB: bound’s ‘>>>=’.
```

You can rearrange this in different ways depending on your use case:

- Adding a constructor to `Prop` wrapping a single `Term`:

  ```
  data Prop a
    = And (Prop a) (Prop a)
    | Relation String [Term a]
    | Forall (Scope () Prop a)
    | Term (Term a)
  ```
- Making `Exp` a sum of `Term` or `Prop` and implementing `Applicative` & `Monad` for that:

  ```
  data Exp a
    = Term (Term a)
    | Prop (Prop a)
  ```
- Making `Exp` a GADT indexed by whether it’s an atomic term or a general proposition:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

  data Class = Atomic | Compound

  data Exp (c :: Class) a where
    V        :: a                  -> Term a
    Func     :: String -> [Term a] -> Term a
    And      :: Prop a -> Prop a   -> Prop a
    Relation :: String -> [Term a] -> Prop a
    Forall   :: Scope () Prop a    -> Prop a

  type Term a = Exp 'Atomic a
  type Prop a = Exp 'Compound a
  ```
- Making `newtype` wrappers with smart constructors for the “subtypes” of `Exp` if you only need to differentiate them sometimes:

  ```
  newtype Term a = Term (Exp a)
  newtype Prop a = Prop (Exp a)

  term :: Exp a -> Maybe (Term a)
  term t = case t of
    V{}    -> yes
    Func{} -> yes
    _      -> no
    where
      yes = Just (Term t)
      no  = Nothing

  prop :: Exp a -> Maybe (Prop a)
  prop t = case t of
    …
  ```

But whichever way, you need `V` in there to express “propositions can *be* variables” or “expressions can be either propositions or variables”. In fact, I think you *could* actually express that with your type as-is, using a dummy relation: `pure a = Relation "" [V a]`, but one of these other forms is probably cleaner.

Comment: Ah yeah, I can see that using a GADT indexed by type would work - I was hoping to avoid that though - seems like I can't!

Comment: @B.Mehta: I edited to add a basic example of doing that. It’s not so bad, although I don’t think you’ll be able to make a `Monad` instance directly, because the types won’t line up; you might need to wrap it in an existential hiding that type parameter, and dispatch on the hidden type, at which point you might as well just use a sum type instead. (GADTs *are* very useful when you do need them, but there are often simpler solutions when you don’t absolutely need them.)